# is this a xss attack,why it is invalid?

Tags: xss

To test a xss attack,i have the following code :

```xml
<html>
    <head><title>test xss</title></head>
    <body>
       <input type="text" id="my_user_name_show" value="">
       <script>
           var s = '"/><script>alert(\'xss\');</script><br class="';
           document.getElementById('my_user_name_show').value= s;
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

why can't the code trigger the alert(xss)?

Answer (score 0):

XSS attacks against input form values have to be triggered from the backend when the actual *HTML* is changed, thus causing

```
 <input type="text" id="my_user_name_show" value=""/>
 <script>alert('xss');</script>
 <br class="">
```

to be written, which obviously will cause it to trigger an alert. On the other hand your code will simply cause

```
<input type="text" id="my_user_name_show" value="\"/><script>alert('xss');</script><br class=\"">
```

to be placed inside the DOM, thus not causing any alert, because no script element is added to the DOM.

Comment: so in this example , in which form of the string s will cause the alert. i have that var s = '\"\/><script>alert(\/xss\/);<\/script><br class=\"', but it is also invalid.

Comment: It's not about the string, it's about the way it's placed in the code. You can not (realistically) cause a XSS attack through javascript (you can through innerHTML, but that's kinda rare).

Comment: so that's no idea to close the input tag and generate a script tag through this way?

Comment: if i use a templeate ,such  <input type="text" id="my_user_name_show" value="{tmp}"/>, and dynamic fill the value property through a string returned from server, may it cause a xss attack ?

Comment: If it goes through javascript and you use the value property, then no, you can not cause a xss attack. (Only once you would use innerHTML or do something along the lines of an eval are you in danger)